# Eclipse java project suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I had my hibernate/sevrlet project working fine in eclipse yesterday,
but now I'm suddenly getting `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions and
unresolved imports that require me **to add to the build path** and
check entries on the properties order & export tab.

All I did since it last worked was work on a different project which shouldn't have affected this particular project.

Why would my project suddenly start requiring all this configuring now, whereas it worked before?

Comment: My guess is that you might have changed some of the dependencies or something.

Comment: this problem is really hard to solve remote.... give us more information

Comment: in eclise, mouse over the error in the java source file, wait for the context menu to show, then select "fix problem"

Comment: @Bloodcount, are you referring to dependency changes globally, or in this project?

Comment: @PhillipSander, well I've fixed a lot but am now getting "Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException" which I'll fix on my own, but I don't know what changed that triggered all these exceptions suddenly

Answer (score 1):

Your class-path probably got broken when you switched projects.

Eclipse usually does some background work upon closing and re-opening a project. Depending on your version, some things could have happened like Maven dependencies (if you use Maven) not being re-added in the deployment assembly.

When all of the sudden Eclipse begins causing me this kind of trouble, I do the following:

- Refresh all the projects (click + F5 on all the projects)
- Clean the server for a full reload
- Sometimes, Project -> Clean also works

Usually any broken reference I have gets fixed by this. Still, check your project's deployment assembly to see if anything that should be there is amiss.

Finally, the definitive test is to open your file system's server folder and check what has been deployed there. If a class is missing, you will see that the jar is not in its place. Assuming you work with Tomcat, the physical location of your server will be somewhere like:

(Eclipse workspace folder).metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but do you have any tips on how to avoid classpath/dependency changes from unexpectedly happening in the future, so that when I get a project working, I can get a warm & fuzzy feeling that it will not unexpectedly break?

Comment: Breakings solved by refreshing the project usually happen when some other program may touch the files in the workspace (manual repository updates from outside Eclipse, or editing a file in a text editor outside Eclipse), so avoiding them should help.

As for the other cases, they mostly happen in my case when I open and close projects. I'm afraid the above routine has become pretty much part of my daily bread and crumbs when using this IDE.